# maxLength in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Supposing the below code:

```js
class Button extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return(

<button 

onClick = {() => this.props.handleInput(this.props.value)} 

value = {this.props.value}>
{this.props.value}

</button>

  )
  }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     input: ''
    }
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleInput(value){
   this.setState( state => ({
    input: state.input += value
    }))
  }

 handleInputChange(event){
  const {value, maxLength} = event.target;
  const limitedMessage = value.slice(0,maxLength)
  this.setState({
   input: limitedMessage
  })
  }
  
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <input
    onChange = {this.handleInputChange}
    type = 'text' 
    value = {this.state.input}
    maxLength = '3'
    />
    <Button handleInput = {this.handleInput} value = '1' />
    <Button handleInput = {this.handleInput} value = '2' />
    <Button handleInput = {this.handleInput} value = '3' />
    <Button handleInput = {this.handleInput} value = '4' />
    <Button handleInput = {this.handleInput} value = '5' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

I'm unsure why maxLength isn't working for buttons that are updating the display textbox value state. When I type into the textbox, the maxLength is being managed. I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

https://jsfiddle.net/rtlatelpa/dxr4ycsj/

Answer (score 1):

You should also handle the maxLength of text inside the `handleInput` like you did in `handleInputChange`.

```js
handleInput(value) {
  let { input } = this.state;
  input += value
  this.setState(state => ({
    input: input.slice(0, 3)
  }))
}
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6kbq8d5/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @rtlatelpa4 happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Because in this function:

```
handleInput(value){
  this.setState( state => ({
    input: state.input += value
  }))
}
```

You forgot to check the maxLength, so it appends `value` to `state.input` in any case

Comment: Yes I see now. Thanks!